# SharePoint custom timer job does not execute

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, custom-timer-job, timer-service, owstimer

I have a custom timer job that inserts into 3 lists.  I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S) and it was working perfectly fine, I was able to debug and deploy the timer without any problems.  Now a few weeks back, our development server crashed but fortunately, I was able to retrieve our content databases.  When I deployed and tested our custom timer jobs, I noticed that it doesn't execute anymore.  It just goes through the base constructor but never to the Execute function.  I have already done the following:

- restart the SharePoint Timer Service, IIS and the server itself
- increased the version of the timer code
- cleared the config cache
- create a new and simple custom timer job
- ran the SharePoint Products Configuration

But none of them works.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Has anything changed with the three lists? For a lack of other options (you've exhausted most of what I would try) I would put the timer job into a Console window and setup some breakpoints or console logging to see more information about what's happening.

Comment: hi ElvisLikeBear, nope, no change in any of the lists.  I'll give your suggestion a try.  Hopefully I can figure this out.  It's almost our deadline.

Comment: No worries @joanna, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong.  It was our old web application, maybe it somehow got damaged during the server crash.  So I created a new web application and tested the timer there.  It worked fine.  Hope this can help somebody out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very silly alternative but it has worked for me many times when I have faced a similar situation. Create a new timer job with a new name copying all the logic from this timer job and deploy it. Most probably it will work.

Comment: hi Mancy, I also did this.  Copied all the logic into a new project, still the same result.  Thanks for the suggestion though.